# How can I download a file from a Redirected URL in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file, url, download

how do I download the csv file from the link below? The link below seems to be a redirect and I could not download it with WebClient and save it in the desired path.

https://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/chart/data/Financial.aspx?i=57086055330734195&t=ph&a=1

When I download from the URL with the WebClient C#, some HTML text is downloaded instead of CSV

Comment: I couldn't reproduce, I didn't download some HTML text but a gzip compressed data, and I could retrieve the csv content by decompressing the stream.

Comment: please show relevant code you tried. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can decompress gzip with the code below and save the final csv file.

```
string downloadUrl = "https://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/chart/data/Financial.aspx?i=57086055330734195&t=ph&a=1";
string saveFilePath = @".\test.csv";

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    // Download file data.
    byte[] downloadedFileData = client.DownloadData(downloadUrl);

    // Save downloaded file to memory.
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(downloadedFileData))
    {
        // Create save file to storage stream.
        using (FileStream saveFileStream = File.Create(saveFilePath))
        {
            // Decompress and create stream to saved gzip from memory.
            using (GZipStream decompressedGZipStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                // Save decompressed gzip to storage.
                decompressedGZipStream.CopyTo(saveFileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```